# Grouping characters to form strings

Tags: ruby, string, char

I've just started learning Ruby and can't figure this out.  Say I have an array:

```
s = ["p", "e", "n", "c", "i", "l"]
```

How can I change the array so that that characters form a word like:

```
t = ["pencil"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1.9.3-p194 :003 > s = ["p", "e", "n", "c", "i", "l"]
=> ["p", "e", "n", "c", "i", "l"] 
1.9.3-p194 :004 > t = [s.join]
=> ["pencil"]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was using join with improper syntax.